# I can not make my jquery code to work?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660447/jquery-code-not-working)

I can't make my jquery work... This is what I am trying to do:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="try_1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/click.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Hide" id="hide_message"/>
    <p id="message">This is a message</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Click.js:

```
$('#hide_message').click(function() {
    $('#message').hide();
});
```

Comment: Define "I can not get it to work". Be more specific. What are you expecting it to do, what errors/warnings are thrown during the process? Elaborate!

Answer (score 7):

```
$(function() {
    $('#hide_message').click(function() {
        $('#message').hide();
    });
});
```

Use `$( function() { });` before your code or equivalent `$(document).ready(function() { });` For further reading why it is used?  SEE: [Tutorial](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready)

Answer (score 4):

Your code will execute before the element exists, and therefore won't be able to bind the event handler to it. Wrap your code in a `$(document).ready()` handler so that it executes after the DOM is ready (and the elements exist).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hide_message').click(function() {
        $('#message').hide();
    });
});
```

This is covered in [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready).

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hide_message').click(function() {
        $('#message').hide();
    });
});
```